# Serializing `numpy.dtype` objects: human readable

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, types

A bit of background. I'm building an application/schema for an HDF5 database and part of the API is being able to specify the dtype (and part of the shape) of a dataset when you first construct the HDF5 file, but not necessarily having to write those datasets you specify before the file is closed and the wrapper for File object is deleted. So I want to save that data in the HDF5 file so the application programmer doesn't have to pass those specifications around every time they open the file for writing. I also want to be able to support arbitrary `numpy.dtype`s for those datasets (via the `h5py` library).

Is there a standard/good way to serialize to plain text a numpy dtype object, besides pickling?

I don't want to use pickling because it is not really readable and was thinking something more like a JSON style format.

e.g. for a datatype like this:

```
In [1]: dt
Out[1]: dtype([('one', '<i8'), ('two', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 2):

My working solution is just to use a JSON string:

```
In [1]: dt = numpy.dtype([('one', np.int), ('two', np.float)])
In [2]: dt.descr
Out[2]: [('one', '<i8'), ('two', '<f8')]
In [3]: dt_str = json.dumps(dt.descr)
In [4]: dt_str
Out[4]: '[["one", "<i8"], ["two", "<f8"]]'
```

Which can easily be read back in and converted to a `numpy.dtype`:

```
In [5]: np.dtype([tuple(i) for i in json.loads(dt_str)])
Out[5]: dtype([('one', '<i8'), ('two', '<f8')])
```